# Normalization vs compression

Tags: amazon-redshift, data-modeling

I'm receiving messages from sensors into Kinesis, process it using lambda and load to Redshift using Kinesis Firehose. All messages are parsed and inserted into one large staging table. We need to do aggregation/analytics of sensor data. Beside sensor data, there are also a lot of info in the header we store but currently don't use.

Does it make sense for me to load data from this staging table into normalized star schema or just enable compression on columns and use one huge denormalized table instead? How well Redshift works with denormalized data? Pros and cons of both options?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "normalized star schema" - by definition, star schemas are *denormalized*.

Comment: Why don't you test out your hypothesis. Try loading tge data into a star schema , benchmark your most frequent queries and size of the tables. And load the data into one large table and do the same. You will have your answer. It really depends on the use case for the table and size of data. No "right way" to go about this.

Comment: @Nathan You are right, I meant snowflake-like with normalized dimensions

Answer (score 1):

In my experience huge tables with lots of columns cause slow queries. If you create narrower tables instead of a wide ones you might get better performance. Before deciding what to do you should consider the queries for analysis and the queries for creating aggregate tables as well as sparsity of the data. On the other hand Joins are expensive overall. And if you need a structure requiring a lot of 'join' then you should adjust the sort and dist keys accordingly. 
Here is the documentation https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/optimizing-for-star-schemas-and-interleaved-sorting-on-amazon-redshift/